# .Net 4.0 C# When loading SHA256 key SignatureAlgorithm changes to SHA1

Tags: c#, .net, sha256, signedxml, xml-dsig

I'm struggling with this now a whole week and hope someone could help me out.

I need to sign xml using SHA256 and xmldsig. 
For this I use the SignedXML Class. When looking into this class I see it uses the SignatureAlgorithm value of the loaded key to determine what Hashing type to use.

No matter how I load the key(via cert store of via loading cert file) it will show SHA1 as SignatureAlgorithm.
When I look up the details of my Certificate in the MMC cert store, it shows SHA256 as SignatureAlgorithm.

I tried both openssl and makecert to generate a SHA256 cert key, but both will load as SHA1 in .Net
And so signedXml.ComputeSignature(); will use SHA1 as a SignatureMethod

.Net 4.0 should support SHA256 right?

Comment: Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedinfo.signaturemethod.aspx, it may only be able to handle SHA-1 in SignedXML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that I was probably using the wrong class.

Instead of Microsoft.Web.Services.Security.SignedXml of should use System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.
The latter doesn't use the SignatureAlgorithm of the used key to determine what Algorithm to use. 
Now I can set the Algorithm myself with 'SignedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod' and use a SHA1 key.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a `KeyedHashAlgorithm` object and pass a string corresponding to SHA256 (documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s5zz2x4d(v=vs.100).aspx)).

The corresponding string for SHA256 is `HMACSHA256`

Then pass this object to the `ComputeSignature` method.

The code should be as follows:
`KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create("HMACSHA256");
signedXml.ComputeSignature(kha);`